# What is the message flow of command+q on a Mac

Tags: cocoa, macos, document

I am building a mac application in cocoa and would like to know what is the message flow (method calls) when the user presses command+q. The app uses the document based architecture.

Thanks.

Comment: You should accept some answers if you want people to spend time answering your questions

Comment: Sorry I didn't know I had to do that. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: You don't *have* to do that, but you *should* do it for the correct answer on each of your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple explained this completely in WWDC 2010 session 145: http://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/

You don't need to have attended WWDC to have access to it; the session videos are free to everybody with an ADC account this year.

Comment: Fantastic, I just watched it. Its exactly what I needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It goes up the responder chain like every other key press.  If the first responder cannot or does not want to handle it, it gets passed up to the next in line.  Usually for that key combination, the `NSApplication` instance recognizes it, handles it and consumes it.